# I get cors issue when i try to upload file to S3 with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am following this blog here.I am doing evertyhing the same but i still get cors issue.My cors configuration in the S3 looks liek this

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://appName.herokuapp.com/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: why do you have two AllowedOrigin? You can leave AllowedOrigin - * if you OK with it

Comment: I removed,but it does't work

Comment: what error are you receiving?